# Boost::python: object destroys itself inside a overriden method

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

While embedding python in my application I've faced with problem related to python objects lifetime. My application exports some classes with virtual methods to python, so they can be derived and extended by python code. Application is using python interpreter and calls virtual methods of objects. The problem is that when object's reference counter reaches zero inside of python overridden method, which was called from c++ code, interpreter destroys object immediately. So, if we call such method inside another method of object we will get behavior equivalent to **delete this** statement. Simple test code:

Object:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "C++ deleted" << std::endl;
        std::cout.flush();
    }

    virtual void virtFunc()
    {
    }

    void rmFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "Precall" << std::endl;
        virtFunc();
        std::cout << "Postcall" << std::endl;
        //Segfault here, this doesn't exists. 
        value = 0;
    }
    
private:
    int value;
};
```

Boost::Python module library:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <list>
#include "Types.h"
#include <iostream>

// Policies used for reference counting
struct add_reference_policy : boost::python::default_call_policies
{
    static PyObject *postcall(PyObject *args, PyObject *result)
    {
        PyObject *arg = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0);
        Py_INCREF(arg);
        return result;
    }
};

struct remove_reference_policy : boost::python::default_call_policies
{
    static PyObject *postcall(PyObject *args, PyObject *result)
    {
        PyObject *arg = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0);
        Py_DecRef(arg);
        return result;
    }
};

struct BaseWrap: Base, boost::python::wrapper<Base>
{
    BaseWrap(): Base()
    {
    }
    
    virtual ~BaseWrap()
    {
        std::cout << "Wrap deleted" << std::endl;
        std::cout.flush();
    }

    void virtFunc()
    {
        if (boost::python::override f = get_override("virtFunc"))
        {
            try 
            { 
                f();
            }
            catch (const boost::python::error_already_set& e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    
    void virtFunc_()
    {
        Base::virtFunc();
    }
};

std::list<Base*> objects;

void addObject(Base *o)
{
    objects.push_back(o);
}

void removeObject(Base *o)
{
    objects.remove(o);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pytest)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base", init<>())
    .def("virtFunc", &Base::virtFunc, &BaseWrap::virtFunc_);
    
    def("addObject", &addObject, add_reference_policy());
    def("removeObject", &removeObject, remove_reference_policy());
}
```

Application, linked with module:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <list>
#include "Types.h"

extern std::list<Base*> objects;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    try
    {
        boost::python::exec_file("fail-test.py", main_namespace);
    }
    catch(boost::python::error_already_set const &)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    sleep(1);
    objects.front()->rmFunc();
    sleep(1);
}
```

fail-test.py:

```
import pytest

class Derived(pytest.Base):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       pytest.Base.__init__(self)
       pytest.addObject(self)
       
   def __del__(self):
       print("Python deleted")
       
   def virtFunc(self):
       pytest.removeObject(self)
           
o1 = Derived(None)
o1 = None
```

Output:

```
Precall
Python deleted
Wrap deleted
C++ deleted
Postcall
```

Is there any good way to avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Boost.Python, this can be accomplished by using [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#deleter_constructor) to manage the lifetime of the objects.  This is normally done by specifying the `HeldType` when exposing the C++ type via [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec).  However, Boost.Python often provides the desired functionality with `boost::shared_ptr`.  In this case, the [`boost::python::wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/wrapper.html#wrapper-spec-synopsis) type supports conversions.

---

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "C++ deleted" << std::endl; }
  virtual void virtFunc() {}
  void rmFunc()
  {
     std::cout << "Precall" << std::endl;
     virtFunc();
     std::cout << "Postcall" << std::endl;
  }
};

/// @brief Wrap Base to allow for python derived types to override virtFunc.
struct BaseWrap
  : Base,
    boost::python::wrapper<Base>
{
  virtual ~BaseWrap() { std::cout << "Wrap deleted" << std::endl; }
  void virtFunc_() { Base::virtFunc(); }
  void virtFunc()
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    if (python::override f = get_override("virtFunc"))
    {
      try { f(); }
      catch (const python::error_already_set&) {}
    }
  }
};


std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Base> > objects;

void addObject(boost::shared_ptr<Base> o)    { objects.push_back(o); }
void removeObject(boost::shared_ptr<Base> o) { objects.remove(o);    }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pytest)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable >("Base", python::init<>())
    .def("virtFunc", &Base::virtFunc, &BaseWrap::virtFunc_);

  python::def("addObject", &addObject);
  python::def("removeObject", &removeObject);
}

const char* derived_example_py =
  "import pytest\n"
  "\n"
  "class Derived(pytest.Base):\n"
  "  def __init__(self, parent):\n"
  "    pytest.Base.__init__(self)\n"
  "    pytest.addObject(self)\n"
  "\n"
  "  def __del__(self):\n"
  "    print(\"Python deleted\")\n"
  "\n"
  "  def virtFunc(self):\n"
  "    pytest.removeObject(self)\n"
  "\n"
  "o1 = Derived(None)\n"
  "o1 = None\n"
  ;

int main()
{
  PyImport_AppendInittab("pytest", &initpytest);
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object main_module    = python::import("__main__");
  python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

  try
  {
    exec(derived_example_py, main_namespace);
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }

  boost::shared_ptr<Base> o(objects.front());
  o->rmFunc();
  std::cout << "pre reset" << std::endl;
  o.reset();
  std::cout << "post reset" << std::endl;
}
```

And the output:

```
Precall
Postcall
pre reset
Python deleted
Wrap deleted
C++ deleted
post reset
```

---

One final change to note is that:

```
objects.front()->rmFunc();
```

was replaced with:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Base> o(objects.front());
o->rmFunc();
```

This was required because [`std::list::front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) returns a reference to the element.  By creating a copy of the `shared_ptr`, the lifespan is extended beyond the `rmFunc()` call.