# Transferring ownership of Python object to C++ in boost-python

Tags: python, c++, boost, unique-ptr, boost-python

I am trying to expose a C++ gui application to Python via boost-python and have arrived at a bit of an impasse. I am using boost-python 1.67 and Python 3.6. The target platform is Windows x64 and the compiler is VS2017.

In C++, I have an interface, lets call it `Foo`, and another interface, lets call it `FooFactory`. I also have a registry of FooFactories which contains all the FooFactories that are known about. I query this registry to find a factory and then use the factory to create Foos.

`Foo` and `FooFactory` are abstract C++ classes. In the C++ application I have a number of implementations of `Foo` and `FooFactory` already and I would like to enable users of the application to write implementations of `Foo` and `FooFactory` in Python which can then be used in the C++ application like any other `Foo` and `FooFactory`.

Here is a simplified definition of Foo and FooFactory:

```
#include <string>
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo() {}
  virtual std::string getName() = 0;
  virtual void doFooThing() = 0;
};

class FooFactory
{
public:
  virtual ~FooFactory() {}
  virtual Foo* buildFoo() = 0;
};
```

And here is a definition of the wrappers I am using to expose the above classes to boost-python:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

class FooWrapper : public Foo, public boost::python::wrapper<Foo>
{
public:
  ~FooWrapper() {}
  std::string getName() override
  {
    try
    {
      if (boost::python::override func = get_override("getName"))
        return func();

        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_NotImplementedError, "'getName' unimplemented");
        boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
    }
    catch ([[maybe_unused]] boost::python::error_already_set& error)
    {
        PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    }

    return std::string();
  }

  void doFooThing() override
  {
    try
    {
      if(boost::python::override func = get_override("doFooThing"))
      {
        func();
        return;
      }

      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_NotImplementedError, "'doFooThing'");
      boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
    }
    catch([[maybe_unused]] boost::python::error_already_set& error)
    {
      PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    }
  }
};

class FooFactoryWrapper : public FooFactory, public boost::python::wrapper<FooFactory>
{
public:
  ~FooFactoryWrapper() {}

  Foo* build() override
  {
    try
    {
      if(boost::python::override func = get_override("build"))
        return func();

      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_NotImplementedError, "'build' not implemented");
      boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
    }
    catch ([[maybe_unused]] boost::python::error_already_set& error)
    {
        PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    }

    return nullptr;
  }
};

void registerFooFactory(FooFactory* factory)
{
  // fooFactoryRegistry omitted in the interest of brevity
  fooFactoryRegistry->add(factory)
}
```

These objects are exported to python as such:

```
namespace py = boost::python;
py::class_<FooWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
  .def("getName", py::pure_virtual(&Foo::getName));

py::class_<FooFactoryWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("FooFactory")
  .def("build", py::pure_virtual(&FooFactory::build), py::return_value_policy<py::manage_new_object>());

py::def("registerFooFactory", &registerFooFactory);
```

And this is an example script in Python that adds a Foo and a FooFactory:

```
import my_module as m

class FooDerived(m.Foo):
  def getName(self):
    return "FooDerived"

class FooFactoryDerived(m.FooFactory):
  def build(self):
    return FooDerived()

m.registerFactory(FooFactoryDerived())
```

The registry is then used elsewhere in the application to instantiate `Foo`s, after the termination of the Python script. Any `Foo` and `FooFactory` implementations written in Python must remain usable for the duration of the process's life.

When I run the example I have given in my C++ application, boost-python raises a

```
ReferenceException: Attempt to return dangling pointer to object of type: class Foo
```

at the line `return FooDerived()` in Python. I have tried numerous variations of FooFactoryWrapper and FooFactory with various shades of `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::auto_ptr` and `boost::shard_ptr` but none have reliably worked (either I get obscure template errors at compile time or the same result at runtime - a `ReferenceException`).

I was able to work around this with a stomach-churningly terrible hack where I manually call `Py_INCREF()` on the `PyObject*` inside the return value of func(), like so:

```
if(boost::python::override func = get_override("build"))
{
  boost::python::detail::method_result result = func();
  Py_INCREF(result.m_obj.get())
  return result;
}
```

but this solution won't be acceptable for production code. Even when I do this, any time in C++ when I call delete on a Python implementation of Foo, the Python implementation crashes. As an extra limitation I do not have debug symbols for the time being.

I believe that I have fundamentally misunderstood the memory ownership semantics around boost-python. As such, I have a number of questions:

1. Is this type of interface exposeable in boost-python?
2. Is it possible to create instances of Python implementations of C++ interfaces in Python whose ownership is transferred to C++?

I have looked at a number of other examples, including [Boost::python: object destroys itself inside a overriden method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751473/boostpython-object-destroys-itself-inside-a-overriden-method) and [Boost.Python: How to expose std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581679/boost-python-how-to-expose-stdunique-ptr/20738438#20738438) and I have not been able to get this to work for my use case (with two abstract classes), although I am unsure if that is because I have made mistakes or have misunderstood the problem, or because it is not possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the issue that you're telling boost the wrapper functions are `pure_virtual()`?